# How to Measure Reqeust Unit Count of Cosmos DB while using EF Core 3.x or 5.x

Tags: entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Azure Function for my project with Cosmos DB Core SQL API. We are using Entity Framework 3.1 as ORM Framework with Cosmos DB.

I want to measure the Request Unit Count for each request and want to log it somewhere else in Blob Store. It would help me to identify the `expensive` calls and API and later we can look and identify the optimization.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find any option or feature to Measure request unit value for the `Context.SaveChages()` (Add/Update operation) or Lambda Query with predicate (Read/SQL query) operation.

It could be helpful if there is an option to get Request unit value and command type (like Insert, Update, Delete, Point Read, and Query) even from DbContext for the last executed operation on a single `DbSet`

I am also not sure about Cosmos will be storing that information in Application Insight or not as there is no direct link or mapping between Cosmos DB and Application Insight.

Comment: my suggestion would be to look at service-side profiling and reporting against the DB itself to capture what requests are being made from all sources. One option might be Hibernating Rhinos Cosmos DB Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Getting RU charges is now available in EF Core 6.0. You can learn more about this and the other Cosmos DB features from their release notes [What's new in EF Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#diagnostics)

Comment: Hi @mark-brown
Thanks for the answer and link about EF core 6.0 Will definitely look into that and will plan to to update EF Core 6.x